# Correct way to download image Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I have found it difficult to solve quite simple task: how to download image from my remote server?

The easiest way to do it is just:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://myserv/test.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
xamlImageContainer.Source = img;
```

but I think this solution is not ideal, because it can block UI thread (can it?).
So I decided to use "async" approach:

```
async void LoadImage()
{
    xamlImageContainer.Source = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://myserv/test.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
    });
}
```

But on the line `return new BitmapImage` I got UnauthorizedAccessException which says "invalid cross-thread access"!
What is wrong here, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of `BitmapImage` type can only be crated in UI thread. Hence the "invalid cross-thread access".

However, you can set `BitmapImage`'s `CreateOptions` property to `BackgroundCreation`. That way the image is downloaded and decoded in a background thread:

```
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it seemed to work. BitmapImage creates some background threads internally when used like so?

Comment: Apparently yes. See documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes @anderZubi is correct.  CreateOptions is the best solution for this problem, however, if you want to load something from a background thread to the UI thread.  You need to call the Dispatcher.  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => YourMethodToUpdateUIElements());

This will call the method on the UI thread and you will not get AccessViolationException.

Just FYI.